# Unable to change Out Of Office Status in Microsoft Team

Tags: microsoft-teams

I set a Out off Office meeting reminder in future in MS Outlook and now my MS Teams is showing Out Of Office.

I checked the setting in my MS Outlook and also tried to manually change my status in MS Teams but in vain.

Where can I fix my out of office setting so that my MS Team shows normal "Available, Away or Busy" status instead of "out of office available/busy/away" ?

Comment: we could not repro it on our side. Could you please send a video of the issue and your domain

Comment: This happens when a latest release of Team is installed. If someone send you a calendar invite with date ranges from today till future with out-off-office selected, or if you create future out-of-office appointment then Team somehow changing the status to out-of-office. I checked with Microsoft Teams expert professional and he advised me to remove any outlook invite sent to me with out-of-office status from my calendar and it fixed the issue now. I also sent my finding to product support team.

Comment: Just in case someone looking for any info (I don't know if solved):
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/education_ms/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-out-of-office-teams-chat/28c84aa8-c400-4100-878f-bf29daff5b36

Answer (score 2):

The reason may be you have accepted someone’s Out of Office (OOO) appointment. Goto your calendar and reject it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and there is no appointment in Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the similar issue like below.

1. Go to your Outlook and Click on File
2. Make sure to check this option (Do not send automatic replies)

Answer (score 1):

1.first turn off automatic reply.

2.Sync your email from outlook by send/receive -> update folder. It will connect 
 with outlook server. Once it is synced your teams status will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Type /busy in your teams search box .

[image]